# How to clean files easily?

Tags: data-cleaning

I am a Bi developer in Microsoft Sql server for a while now.
I have always worked with ether an almost clean data which is excel files with first row is the headings that does have too much rubbish in sheets(like irrelevant data, calculations and so on), text files  with data separated by a comma (csv files)
Or with relatively small amounts of files which I cleaned manually(it wasn't an issue)

In my new job I am getting many not clean files, examples are: plain text files (not csv) and excel files the opposite of the mentioned above.

My problem is that these files are many and going through every file is upsetting (opening cleaning manually and trying to make any sense of the data within) so finally I can load it to an integration service tool (ssis, Informatica) and then to a Viz tool through a data warehouse.

Viz tool like Tableau desktop can't clean them appropriately with the automatic interpretation (it takes only the main tables and ignore the others with these not clean files)

I am sure someone worked with these things, your help would be appreciated!

How to deal with these situations?

Comment: I think the question is too broad. You should be more specific about your problem. You cannot ask for a solution for different dirty files having different formats. For example, you should ask a question about the unstructured text files by providing sample data, target schema, what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding . I had almost 25 flat files (not Csv.) flat/plain text, these files almost looked like data by columns but not exactly. I examined each file manually and didn't find any information that I can make sense of, I tried loading them to Tableau Desktop to make any sense of the data, but didn't succeed (I couldn't clean them in Tableau). I don't know what to do , What should be my approach in this case ? should I clean each file manually ? I am not an expert in cleaning unstructured files (plain txt or excel file) what is the best option in this case ?